STM CUBE IDE ENUM issue
I create a Enum table in the STM32 CUBE IDE V1.8 and I have about 160 index's within, when I program my STM32 and enter Debug mode, the index after number 127 obtains the value -128 followed by -127,-126. my understanding was that enums are int16. The values are incorrect before I run the init function. when not in debug mode all values are correct.
typedef enum
{
  OneIndex,
  TwoIndex,
  ThreeIndex,
  FourIndex,`
  .....
  Last index
}Index_Value_Type;

I have tried ChatGPT recommendations with no success.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify and add information. -- Some compilers optimize enums to the minimum necessary width, in your case apparently int8_t or signed char. Please add the command lines to build your program, I'm sure you can copy them verbatim from your IDE. -- BTW, don't trust chat bots. They have no understanding in programming.

Your question has nothing to do with literally any of the tags. This is a pure C/C++ question (indicate which one, please).

How are you displaying/viewing the enum value?  Perhaps you have inadvertently cast it to a signed 8-bit type.
